# Elixir File.read returns empty data when accessing /proc/cpuinfo

Tags: erlang, elixir

When running any thing like

```
File.read "/proc/cpuinfo"
>> {:ok, ""}
```

Same for equivalent erlang function. Is there some reason for this pattern?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like @José mentioned the proc fs is special since the file contents are generated on the fly. If you look at the file sizes in /proc you'll see that they have size `0`.

I believe this is why the `read` function fails to return anything, the file is empty!

The workaround is to force-read a number of bytes anyway, in Erlang you can do:

```
{ok, FD} = file:open("/proc/cpuinfo", [read]).
file:read(FD, 1024).
```

To read all the content keep reading fixed number of bytes until EOF is returned by `read`.

Comment: Created equivalent in **elixir**  
`File.stream!("/proc/cpuinfo",[], :line) |> Enum.each (fn chunk -> String.strip(chunk) |> IO.puts  end)`

Comment: Thanks for the elixir version. I had to tweak it slightly to get rid of ambiguous piping into a function call. I'm looking at meminfo instead. `File.stream!("/proc/meminfo",[], :line) |> Enum.each(fn chunk -> String.strip(chunk) |> IO.puts() end)`

Answer (score 4):

Entries in proc live under a special filesystem called procfs and I believe Erlang does not support reading from it. More info: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121702/what-happens-when-i-run-the-command-cat-proc-cpuinfo